# How to programmatically erase all populated column data in a Databound DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've been using the following VB code to erase all populated entries in a databound DatagridView;

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView.Rows

      row.Cells(columnIndex).Value = DBNull.Value

Next
```

However, due to some weird behaviour I encountered, I have now learned that if the DataGridView has been populated by DataSource = x (i.e. is databound) then I need to change the bound data, not the DataGridView cells themselves.

Question is, how do I go about changing the above code?

Comment: `myDGV.DataSource = Nothing`

Comment: It doesnt "erase" the data, just removes it from view - it will still be loaded into your app and reside in the DB (if that is where it came from).  The user just cannot see it

Comment: I need to erase the column data permanently from the database and then update the DGV to reflect that.

Comment: Then you need to delete or Truncate Table

Comment: Negative. The table layout must remain the same. I should be able to replace the erased column data with new data.

Comment: By delete I meant delete the rows in the DB table.  Truncate (if allowed) would do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the data source is a datatable (mdt):

```
    For Each row As DataRow In mdt.Rows
        row.Delete()
    Next
```

This changes your in memory copy of the data. You would need so save the data to change the data on the server.

Comment: That deletes the whole row, not just the one cell the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to do the trick...

Dim selectedRow As DataRowView

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows

```
selectedRow = CType(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
selectedRow(ColumnIndex) = DBNull.Value
dgv.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(True)
```

Next